# Is it better to check if a variable already has that value before assigning it?

Tags: algorithm

I'm sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, but: let's say that I have to change the bool variable 'a', based on a condition 'cond', but it could happens that 'a' already has the value I want to assign to it.

Now, should I do something like this:

```
// something that changes 'a'

if (cond) {
    a = true;
}
```

or should I check before if the variable 'a' is already true, like this:

```
// something that changes 'a'

if (cond) {
    if (!a) {
         a = true;
    }
}
```

Which way is faster? (and if there are differences in different programming languages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use whatever is most clear to express your code's intent, which is usually the direct `a = true;`.  A good compiler will optimize a boolean `if (!a) { a = true; }` into `a = true;` so the same performance can be expected.

Avoid [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).